# Microsoft Word 2007 documents dissapear off screen when opened

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have Windows 7 and Microsoft Office with Word 2007. When I try to open a document it disapears off the screen and can't be seen. If I open Word with winword.exe /a it works OK. I have deleted the normal.dot file but this has made no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: single monitor?

Comment: Yes single monitor.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Nothing obvious in Event Viewer. Problem is now solved and has not reoccured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the registry, try to rename the:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Data
```

key to OldData. When you restart Word, a new Data key will be written. This might help.

Comment: This worked. Brilliant, thanks for your help, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

Make sure the document window is in focus even if you can't see it (try alt tabbing to it)
Then use the keyboard shortcut:
Alt+Space then M  then Arrow Keys

It will let you move the window around using the keyboard instead of the mouse so you can move it back to your visible monitor.

Comment: Tried this, did not solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Word on a second monitor before? If that was the case it remembers the last window position and since your second monitor might not be on/connected right now you get the soft confused. Strange anyway.

Comment: I have only ever used one monitor.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick easy one-off fix if Word has opened off screen (I don't know why it's only Word that seems to do this)

- *(Make sure Word is the program selected in the Task bar at the bottom. If it's not, select it)*
- **Hold the Windows key, and press an arrow key** (up, left, right, but not down).

This jumps the window around between different pre-set screen positions (up fills the screen, left fills left half of screen, right fills right half, etc).

You may need to repeat, mix or cycle through different arrow key presses to convince Word to put the doc on the actual screen not whatever non-existent non-screen it thinks the document is on.